# Extract Amazon ASIN from URL with MySql Regex

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, select

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  url, 
  url REGEXP '/([A-Z0-9]{10})' as asin 
FROM urls;
```

I am trying to extract the ASIN portion of an amazon url.

my query simply returns 1 for a match, and 0 for a non-match. How do I actually extract this with mysql (DB level) without having to run the regex at the application level?

Comment: I think you will have to use a combination of `locate` and `substr`, you can use a `where` to first make sure the record matches your format.

Comment: Show us an example url.

Comment: @RickJames Im not sure how an example url would help. The url could be any string, but I want to extract the portion which matches my regex. if you still want the example URL - http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00BE4HOIM where `B00BE4HOIM` is the ASIN. However depending on how the user got to the page, the URL could be something like http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00BE4HOIM?keywords=playstation%204&qid=1453711265&ref_=sr_tr_sr_2&s=videogames&sr=1-2

Answer (score -1):

MySQL's regexp can locate rows, but not extract the matching text.

This may work for that example:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', -1)
```

Example:

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00BE4HOIM', '/', -1);
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX('amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00BE4HOIM', '/', -1) |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| B00BE4HOIM                                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This *assumes* there is nothing *after* the ASIN.  If there could be, then perhaps a second step could strip that stuff.